# Does any "probe" exist which can detect the gravity of wort?

Tags: specific-gravity

I use a Raspberry Pi in combination with a temperature probe to measure the temperature of my wort. It would be nice if I had another probe that could measure the current gravity of my beer, so that my RPi could instruct my fermwraps to heat up once primary fermentation is complete.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is the [beerbug](http://www.thebeerbug.com/), a wifi/bluetooth SG sensor.

Comment: beerbug has an API in the works to allow access for applications like this.

Comment: Any idea on how it works?

Comment: It appears to be driven by weight/gravity: The BeerBug sits on top of your fermenter in the bung/stopper, and a weight hangs from it through the stopper and submerged in the wort/beer, attached by fishing line. I'm assuming it monitors the amount of pull the suspended weight is exerting on the controller, which increases as the gravity of the wort/beer decreases. You have to tare it by giving it your initial gravity, taken with a standard hydromoter or refractometer.

Comment: I should add that I have not actually used mine yet -- I just received it a few weeks ago, and have not had a chance to brew since.